# Xamarin Forms ListView not showing content

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am rendering this `ListView`

```
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="Test"/> //This Label is getting rendered
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                SeparatorColor="DarkGray">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Whose ItemsSource is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Music>` which is available in the `ViewModel`.This is how i am binding the `ViewModel`

```
public MainPage()
{
    BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This is my `ViewModel` and here im calling the API methods to get the data.and

```
    private ObservableCollection<Music> _MusicList=new ObservableCollection<Music>();
    public ObservableCollection<Music> MusicList
    {
        get { return _MusicList; }
        set
        {
            if (_MusicList != value)
            {
                _MusicList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("_MusicList");
            }
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        api = new ApiHelper();
        GetSongs();
    }

    public async void GetSongs()
    {
        _MusicList = new ObservableCollection<Music>(await api.GetMusicListAsync());
    }
```

The data is coming in the `ObservableCollection<Music>` [image]

**UPDATE**

Just for testing I tried binding a simple string List `ListStrings = new List<string> {"A","B","C","D","E","F" };` but it also didnt show up.

**UPDATE**
Now i override onAppearing method and initialized my list and set ListView ItemsSource to it. and its working now..but dont know why its not working with binding.

Comment: Replace this `MusicList = new ObservableCollection<Music>(await api.GetMusicListAsync());` with this `_MusicList = new ObservableCollection<Music>(await api.GetMusicListAsync());`

Comment: Do you have a Property `Name` in your `Music` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I found the solution.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this; //Added this 
    }
```

Just Added `BindingContext = this;` in the constructor.I don't know whats wrong with Xamarin think its a bug.

Comment: I followed @Gerald Versluis  's answer and it worked. I was creating a new Observable when receiving the data and I should just use 'add() method' from the Observable. Also, I had to initialize the Observable in the constructor of my ViewModel.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of things that could be problematic.

1. `ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList,Mode=TwoWay}"` is there a good reason to make it TwoWay? If not, don't do it.
2. Set your `BindingContext` after the `InitializeComponent();`
3. Do not create a new `ObservableCollection` when you get data. By creating a new collection, you lose the data binding. Instead, change it like this:

   ```
   public async void GetSongs()
   {
       var result = await api.GetMusicListAsync();

       foreach (var r in result)
           _MusicList.Add(r);
   }
   ```

Comment: sorry to say but nothing helped..i override the onAppearing method then it showed the list.. dont understand the problem yet :/

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

I think you made mistake Raising Property Changed :

```
private ObservableCollection<Music> _MusicList=new 
ObservableCollection<Music>();
public ObservableCollection<Music> MusicList
{
    get { return _MusicList; }
    set
    {

            _MusicList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MusicList");  //You should raise property change on your Binding variable.

    }
}
```

Just like @Gerald said, Follow his advice and I'm adding to give you idea solving the 3rd problem he mentioned.

If you create your Observable Collection every time when you get data, you loose the data binding. If you use foreach method that will raise collection change event multiple times, if you have large list it might be problem for you.

Following Extended collection supports different types of collection and has property to Reset observable collection.

On your View Model Constructor you can Initialize your collection once like :

```
public MusicPageViewModel()
{
     MusicsData=new ExtendedCollection<Music>();
}
```

Then whenever you will get data from your API you will do something like :

```
public GetMusicsData()
{
     MusicsData.Reset(YourApi.GetMusics());
}
```

I hope it helps you implementing your Observable collection. This is the Extended Observable collection you can use and extend it further more if you need to:

```
public class ExtendedCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ExtendedCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }
    public ExtendedCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedCollection(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset the existings items and fills the new items provided.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range"></param>
    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();

        if (range != null)
        {
            AddRange(range);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add all items in the range;
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range"></param>
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        foreach (var item in range)
        {

            Items.Add(item);
        }

        //Raise the property change!
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to say but nothing helped..i override the onAppearing method then it showed the list.. dont understand the problem yet :/

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved changing the way of declaring properties in the observed object. Example:

This failed

```
public class MusicItem
{
     public string Name;
}
```

This worked sucessfully:

```
public class MusicItem
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The Binding fails to find the property Name in the first example, but worked in the second one.